# A variable has a value but throws an object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datatable, backgroundworker, void, spreadsheetlight

I have a function that loops a `DataTable` and saves it as an `Excel File` using `SpreadSheetLight` for `C#`

noticing that looping through the `DataTable` and saving its `Excel File` output takes time depending on how many cells and rows and columns a `DataGrid` had, or wherever that `DataTable` was extracted from.

before using `BackgroundWorker` in my function, the function executes properly. the only sidenote without `BackgroundWorker` of course is that the UI freezes while the codes executes. and by utilizing `BackgroundWorker` i know i can eliminate this by processing the save function on another thread.

but after applying `BackgroundWorker` in my function, the whole save function breaks. it throws me an `Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object` but i debugged and traced and made myself sure that both the variables passed had values in it, and is not null. the loop i used was the same as before, and i've even tried using a `For Loop`.

here is a snippet of what i've encountered. and as you can see, the window below shows that the `cell` and `value` variable both has contents in it. yet throws me null reference.

[image]

moreover, here is the complete code of my function

```
        public void exportSingleDataGridToExcelFile(DataTable dt) {
            using(var sfd = new SaveFileDialog()) {
                sfd.FileName = string.Format("WIP Monitoring-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));
                sfd.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

                if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                    clb.Enabled = false;
                    cb.Enabled = false;
                    btn.Visible = false;
                    pb.Visible = true;
                    pb.Value = 50;

                    using(var excel = new SLDocument()) {
                        var style = excel.CreateStyle();
                        style.SetHorizontalAlignment(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.HorizontalAlignmentValues.Center);
                        style.SetVerticalAlignment(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.VerticalAlignmentValues.Center);

                        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

                        bgw.DoWork += (ss, ee) => {
                            var worker = ss as BackgroundWorker;

                            var count = (dt.Rows.Count + 1) * dt.Columns.Count;
                            var steps = (double) count / 100;
                            var prog = 0.0;
                            var row = 0;
                            var col = 0;

                            //Get Column Headers
                            foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
                                var cell = string.Format("{0}1", col.getExCol());
                                var value = dc.ColumnName;

                                excel.SetCellValue(cell, value);
                                excel.AutoFitColumn(string.Format("{0}1", col.getExCol()));
                                excel.SetCellStyle(string.Format("{0}1", col.getExCol()), style);

                                prog += steps;
                                worker.ReportProgress(((int) prog * 100));

                                col++;
                            }

                            col = 0;

                            //Get Cell Data
                            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
                                foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
                                    var cell = string.Format("{0}{1}", col.getExCol(), row);
                                    var value = dr[dc].ToString();

                                    excel.SetCellValue(cell, value);
                                    excel.AutoFitColumn(cell, row);
                                    excel.SetCellStyle(cell, style);

                                    prog += steps;
                                    worker.ReportProgress(((int) prog * 100));

                                    col++;
                                }
                                col = 0;
                                row++;
                            }
                        };

                        bgw.ProgressChanged += (ss, ee) => {
                            pb.Value = ee.ProgressPercentage / 100;
                        };

                        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (ss, ee) => {
                            try {
                                excel.SaveAs(sfd.FileName);
                                form.Close();
                            } catch(Exception ex) {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error while saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            }
                        };

                        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

originally, this same code worked before i've implemented my `BackgroundWorker`.

hoping i could receive some walk through here.

Comment: the `excel` variable from the `using` statement doesn't get passed on to the `bgw.DoWork` event handler

Comment: Very good question display btw ; nicely laid out with much information.

Comment: @Claies seems like it. thank you for noticing it for me

Comment: @Zil well, i need to portray my question as good as i can so others can understand what my problem is. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly probable that something inside the `SLDocuemnt` instance in `excel` is `null` when your background worker is executed.

You are creating `excel` in a `using` statement. That means that at the end of the `using` block, `excel` will be disposed. But inside that block you start a background worker that uses this `excel` variable.

The background worker surely runs longer than your `using` block, so `excel` is already disposed when you try to access it and execute the line that throws the exception.

The *immediate solution* would be to not use `using` here. But maybe it's better to instantiate that `excel` variable *inside* the background worker's method, as it seems you don't need it outside anyway.

Comment: we suspect the same thing too. after posting this question i've tried to remove the using block and declaring the `excel` variable on top of the function. the problem went out and i got it working again. i think i'll leave this question here in case some other people thought of the same thing as i did. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your  `excel` variable is the one that is Null, when reading the exception. Not the values in the method call.

I suspect this is due to the background work your doing.

Comment: i removed the using(){}; block and things went well again. thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
public FileStreamResult GenerateReport()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
    {
        sl.SetCellValue("B3", "I love ASP.NET MVC");
        sl.SaveAs(ms);
    }
    // this is important. Otherwise you get an empty file
    // (because you'd be at EOF after the stream is written to, I think...).
    ms.Position = 0;

    return File(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");
}
```

Comment: Ho sdfds. Are you sure that this answer is relevant to the question asked? It looks off topic to me.